# How to set a hidden back-up email on Github?

Tags: github

I have a public email I use for git commits and I am trying to figure out if it's possible to add a hidden backup email to my account without having it be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Setting a backup email address](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-a-backup-email-address) section of the Github docs.

> Use a backup email address as an additional destination for security-relevant account notifications and to securely reset your password if you can no longer access your primary email address.

This should, of course, be different from the emails you use for commits. From your profile, go to the **Emails** section, add a new email address and select it from the dropdown of the **Backup email address** section.

[image: Github Email Settings]

In addition, you may want to also check the **Keep my email addresses private** option to hide your email "*when performing web-based Git operations (e.g. edits and merges) and sending email on your behalf.*"

Comment: This is not a correct answer. Setting a backup email will make it pubicly visible as your main email, while checking option *Keep my email address**ES** private* will make **all of them** private. There doesn't seem to be an option to have main email public for commits and a backup email that's private and entirely hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The not perfect soultion to that seems to be keeping **Keep my email addresses private** checked, and disabling **Block command line pushes that expose my email**. In that way all email addresses (main and backup ones) will be hidden directly on your profile, but it will still be possible to create commits using them. Just keep in mind that you will also be able to expose your backup email if you happened to create a commit using it.